# What kind of object is getElementByID outputting to here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working through *How to Learn Javascript Properly* and came across this interesting code example in O'Reilly's *Javascript the Definitive Guide 6th ed.*

Update: A better way of asking the question - what is an element returned by `getElementById()`? At first it looks like it is the text inside the target `<div>`, but at other times it looks like `[object HTMLDivElement]`. What is actually in the `elements` object?

HTML:

```
<div id="id1">some text id1</div>
<div id="id2">some text id2</div>
```

JS:

```
function getElements( /*ids...*/ ) {
    var elements = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var id = arguments[i];
        var elt = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elt == null) {
            throw new Error("No element here");
        }
        elements[id] = elt;
    }
    //alert(Array.isArray(elements)); //false
    return elements;
}

var elements = getElements("id1",  "id2");
//alert(Array.isArray(elements)); //false
//alert(elements[0]); //undefined
alert(elements["id1"]); //[object HTMLDivElement]
```

The code outputs `some text id1` and `some text id2` on separate lines in [JSFiddle's Results pane](http://jsfiddle.net/6ry3t/), so it appears to be working.

I'd like to know what is in the object `elements`.

You can see various `alert()`'s I've tried to in order to figure it out in the comments above.

I thought `elements` was an object whose keys were the id's I was looking for (so, `id1` and `id2`) and whose values were the text in those `<div>`s, but when I `alert(elements["id1"]);` on the last line I get a weird output: `[object HTMLDivElement]`. I thought it would output `some text id1`.

Since it doesn't, how does JSFiddle know to output `some text id1` on the Results pane?

Comment: Don't use `alert` to debug your code; use the console. `[object HTMLDivElement]` is the string representation of an element.

Comment: @elclanrs I can't get `console.log()` to output anywhere with JSFiddle :( (also, `alert` seems fine here - `document.write()` does the same thing since they're just calling `.toString()` if i recall correctly)

Okay re: string representation of an element, nonetheless how is the `<div>` text making its way to the Results pane? Where is it coming from, and what is getting access to it?

Comment: Mmm, works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/BgF6E/

Comment: @elclanrs actually you can see it's not working, because the `console.log()` line isn't outputting anything...(try removing it and adding it back in...)

Comment: Did you actually check your browser console?

Comment: What you see in the results-pane is the resulting document based on HTML, Javascript and CSS, what do you expect to see in the results-pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns an object, which is [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) if there is no element with the given `id`, or that element otherwise.

**What does that object look like?**

Well, it's an instance of these constructors:

- [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element)
- [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)
- [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)
- [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Depending on the element, it will also be an instance of [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement), [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement), etc.

**Why do you get `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`?**

When you attempt to use an object as text (e.g. when using `alert`), its [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method is called. And this method return the string `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` when called on a `<div>` element.

If you want to get more useful data, you should use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) and you will be able to inspect its properties.

**How to get the text of an element?**

You can use

- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)
- [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), only on some browsers, non-standard
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), assuming the element only contains text, not other elements.
- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild)`.`[`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue), assuming the element only contains a text node.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Thanks to @Dr.Molle for pointing out the last paragraph in this answer is bunk. While the stuff above it is correct, the reason the Results pane shows the text inside the `<div>` blocks is because *that is what the formatted HTML looks like,* not because the javascript does anything to modify the document. It's still a good idea to read this post to see how someone who doesn't know something can go about researching a plausible answer. That skill, combined with good feedback from SO, helps everyone make progress.

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns an object of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). So when you try to `alert(elements["id1"])` you get `[object HTMLDivElement]` as the output because `alert()` calls `.toString()` behind the scenes. The returned value is `[object HTMLDivElement]` because the item is an object of reference type HTMLDivElement.

If you tried this line `alert(elements["id1"].outerHTML);` you would get

```
<div id = "id1">
    some text id1
</div>
```

This is because `<div id = "id1">` is an Element, and `Element.outerHTML` is a property of Element objects.

But, if you tried this line `alert(elements["id1"].textContent);` you would get `some text id1`. This is because `<div id = "id1">` inherits methods and properties from [the `Node` object type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

So what's happening in your code? the `getElements()` function returns a variable `elements`, which is in fact an object of objects. As you know, objects are just collections of `<key, value>` pairs. The `<key>`'s here are the HTML id's that you passed into `getElements()`. The values are *other objects,* namely, the objects of type `Element` that are returned by `getElementById()`.

When `getElements()` returns `elements`, the returned object is evaluated such that `.textContent` is called behind the scenes to prepare the output, and that is what you are seeing on JSFiddle's Results pane. This is also why trying to `alert(elements["id1"])` did not work, since it calls `.toString()` instead of `.textContent`.

Comment: When getElements() returns elements, the returned object isn't evaluated as anything, it's a simple  object. Again, as already commented to the question: what you see in the results-pane is the resulting document. Your script-code did not modify the document in any manner, what you see there you will also see without any script: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rc44j/